# Adding sets to a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

I have a file `random.txt` from which I need to take each word, and index the position and letter in a dictionary. For example, it would be as follows: `{(3,'m'):'example'}`.  Every time there is a word that has the same indexed letter in the same position it only adds the word to the value of the dictionary, so it'd be `{(3,'m'):'example','salmon'}` and not print each one separately.

This is what I have and it doesn't add the word to the value of the key each time it just makes it's own value each time.

```
def fill_completions(c_dict, fileObj):
    import string
    punc = string.punctuation
    for line in fileObj:
        line = line.strip()
        word_list = line.split()    #removes white space and creates a list
        for word in word_list:
            word = word.lower()     
            word = word.strip(punc) #makes lowercase and gets rid of punctuation
            for position,letter in enumerate(word):
                "position: {} letter: {}".format(position,letter)
                my_tuple = (position,letter)
                if word in my_tuple:
                    c_dict[my_tuple] += word
                else:
                    c_dict[my_tuple] = word
        print(c_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're adding a string, then appending to the string.

You need to put a tuple in as your value, then add to the tuple.

```
>>> m = dict()
>>> m['key'] = 'Hello'
>>> m['key'] += 'World'
>>> print m['key']
HelloWorld
>>>
>>> m['key'] = ('Hello',)
>>> m['key'] += ('World',)
>>> print m['key']
('Hello', 'World')
>>> # Or, if you want the value as a list...
>>> m['key'] = ['Hello']
>>> m['key'].append('World')
>>> print m['key']
['Hello', 'World']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change the code that populates `c_dict` in the innermost loop to the following:

```
            if my_tuple in c_dict:
                c_dict[my_tuple].add(word)
            else:
                c_dict[my_tuple] = set([word])
```

Here is an equivalent version using `dict.setdefault()` that is a bit more concise:

```
            c_dict.setdefault(my_tuple, set()).add(word)
```